# Strange behavior of Split View Controller in iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a strange behavior of Split View Controller in iOS 5.0 and iOS 6.0 iPad simulators. I created Master View Detail template in Xcode and set deployment targets everywhere to 5.0. I switched Autolayout off and set orientation to landscape only.

My app works as follows - Split View Controller is my root VC and because I need to display login first I use

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self presentModalViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginVC"] animated:NO];
}
```

in the MasterViewController. Everything runs smoothly on iOS 6 simulator, but the 5.0 just won't display the login VC and shows the rest in portrait mode, but turned to landscape. Picture attached below.

Anbody knows what could be wrong?

[image: iOS 5 left / iOS 6 right]